# How do I insert someone else's slides into my PowerPoint presentaion?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am putting a PowerPoint presentation together. My version is 2010. How can I insert slides from other classmates (different versions) PowerPoint slides into mine?

Answer (score 1):

Open both presentations, then drag and drop slides from one to the other.

Comment: This may not work across versions, specifically going from 2003 to 2007+, and if the slide master is different. But it is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is for PowerPoint 2007, but it will work for you.

http://www.technipages.com/powerpoint-2007-import-slides-from-another-presentation-file.html

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2010, here's how you can insert slides from another presentation to a presentation you are currently working on:

1. With your current presentation open, go to **Home** tab → **Slides** group → **New Slide** → **Reuse Slides...**

   [image]
2. The **Reuse Slides** task pane will appear on the right side of the PowerPoint window. On the Reuse Slides task pane, click **Browse** and click **Browse File...**

   [image]
3. The Browse dialog box appears allowing you to locate the presentation that contains the slide you want to insert to your current presentation. Select the presentation you want and click **Open**.

   [image]
4. The slides from that presentation will now be listed in the **Reuse Slides** task pane.

   [image]
5. Click the slide you want to insert and it will be added automatically to your current presentation.

   [image]